# self.attr resets between tests in unittest.TestCase

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'd like to use a `self.attr` of a `unittest.TestCase` class, however it seems it is not persistent between tests:

```
import unittest

class TestNightlife(unittest.TestCase):
    _my_param = 0

    def test_a(self):
        print 'test A = %d' % self._my_param
        self._my_param = 1

    def test_b(self):
        print 'test B = %d' % self._my_param
        self._my_param = 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

This gives the following output:

```
test A = 0
test B = 0
```

Does the instance of `unittest.TestCase` change between test runs? Why?

Comment: **Motivation:** Of course you can't assume test order, but sometimes a certain test changes something in the environment and another test should know if it has already been changed or not in order to take or refrain from certain actions. Sometimes it's simpler and more readable to keep this info in a variable instead of having helper functions that inspect report the state. Even if you disagree with this notion, it is still interesting to know what happens to `self` between tests, so the question is interesting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works that way because unittest.main() create separate object for every test (in this case two objects are created).

About your motivation: test should not change global state. You should revert global state to state before test in tearDown or test itself. It's very problematic if tests are changing global state, you will fall in scenarios you can't predict sooner or later.

```
import unittest

class TestNightlife(unittest.TestCase):
    _my_param = 0

    def test_a(self):
        print 'object id: %d' % id(self)
        print 'test A = %d' % self._my_param
        self._my_param = 1

    def test_b(self):
        print 'object id: %d' % id(self)
        print 'test B = %d' % self._my_param
        self._my_param = 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

output:

```
object id: 10969360
test A = 0
.object id: 10969424
test B = 0
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: I fully agree regarding the global state, nonetheless I'm doing it to speedup the tests and `practicality beats purity...`

Comment: btw, do you have a reference to the fact that unittest.main() creates a separate object per test? If so add it and I'll mark the question as accepted

Comment: I don't have reference to documentation, unittest just works that way (see example code).